# Expected primary-expression before token in fscanf command

Tags: c, struct, syntax-error

So a friend of mine sent me this but unfortunately my C skills are a bit rusty so I might be missing something easy. The problem exists in the second `fscanf` command.

The error is `[Error] expected primary-expression before '[' token`. It might be something it's easily missed but I tried searching for a bit before posting this. Any help is appreciated!

```
struct materials
{
  char name,product;
  int code,code1,number_of_parts,quantity1,number_of_parts1,quantity2;     
};
typedef struct materials mater;
int main()
{
 int result(int x)  ; 
 int number1,j,i,result1,number2,k,z; 
 FILE *fp;
    materials* listOfMaterials; 
 fp = fopen("datain.txt", "r");

 if (fp!=NULL)
 {
 fscanf(fp, "%d\n",&number1);

 listOfMaterials = (mater*)malloc(number1 * sizeof( mater));

 for(j=1; j<number1; j++) {
  fscanf (fp, "%d %d %d %s\n", &mater[j].code, &mater[j].quantity1, &mater[j].number_of_parts, mater[j].name);
        if (mater[j].quantity1 != 0)
    {
           mater[j].code1=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*mater[j].quantity1);
           mater[j].number_of_parts1=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * mater[j].quantity1);                     
       fscanf (fp,"%d %d\n",&mater[j].code1,&mater[j].number_of_parts1);      
    }
}
```

Comment: Please sort out the indentation of the code - makes it readable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use scanf \ fscanf to read a line and parse into variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204625/how-to-use-scanf-fscanf-to-read-a-line-and-parse-into-variables)

Comment: Sorry I just signed up here. What can I do to make it more readable?

Comment: `mater[j]` --> `listOfMaterials[j]` , also `j` start from `1`, not `0` ??

Comment: Also, don't cast the return of `malloc`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc, best is to use no casts at all in C.

Answer (score 2):

`typedef struct materials mater` defines a new *type* named `mater`.

Further in the code you attempt to use it as a variable, so I guess you meant define a variable, rather than a type:

```
struct materials mater;
```

or just:

```
materials mater;
```

Comment: I haven't touched C in some months. Mater is my struct variable but the thing I don't understand is if I can consider it as a string so I can do `&mater[j].x`.

Comment: @ahcomm No, `name` and `product` sturct members are single `char`s, not strings. If you want them to be strings, define them as `char *name, *product;`, then *allocate* each of them with `malloc(n)`, so that they will have enough room for `n` chars (incuding null terminator). Or just use C++, and avoid all this mess :).

Comment: I see. As I said a friend of mine asked me to help him with this and I don't want to provide him with false information. Thanks.

Comment: @ahcomm use plain C only you must (kernel module, class assignment, etc.), otherwise use C++ with its Standard Library.

Answer (score 1):

`mater` is a type and not an object, your `scanf` line makes not much sense to me.